# using prototype in custom object in javascript

Tags: javascript, object

I have made my custom object and I want to add a method into. I want to uppercase my values. But it is giving me [object object].Any idea how to get it done. [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/T8w49/)

```
function checkObj (name,title,salary){
    this.name= name;
    this.title= title;
    this.salary= salary;
    }

var woo=new checkObj("rajora","this is a test",2000);
checkObj.prototype.inc=function (){
    for(i=0;i<this.length;i++){
    this[i]= this[i].toUpperCase();
    }
    };
woo.inc();
console.log(woo)
```

Comment: what do you exepct from `console.log(woo)`? `woo` it's your object

Comment: checkObj { name="RAJORA", title="THIS IS A TEST", salary=2000, more...}

Comment: then `console.log(JSON.stringify(woo))` (in your case)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have to change your `inc` function like this

```
checkObj.prototype.inc = function() {
    for (var key in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            if (typeof this[key] === 'string') {
                this[key] = this[key].toUpperCase();
            }
        }
    }
};
```

and this gives me the following output

```
{ name: 'RAJORA', title: 'THIS IS A TEST', salary: 2000 }
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call `console.log()` and pass it an object like `woo`, it uses `woo.toString()` to get the string representation of it and print it.

`woo` inherits `toString()` from `Object.prototype` which by default prints the string you are getting, i.e. `[object object]`.

You have to override `toString()` like this:

```
checkObj.prototype.toString = function() {
    var result = "checkObj {";
    for (var prop in this) {
        if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            result += (prop + " : " + String(this[prop]).toUpperCase() + ", ");
    }
    result += ("}");
    return result;
}
```

Now you can just `console.log(woo)` and it would work as expected.

Comment: Thanks it is giving desired result but it is also throwing error. http://jsfiddle.net/T8w49/2/

Comment: thanks again. One thing i need to know What is prop. Does integer prop

Comment: @amit I have just rolled the final version of the answer, please check edit.

Comment: @amit `prop` is variable that would hold the name of each property on `woo` as it loops on it.

Answer (score 1):

Demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/T8w49/5/).

js code like this :

```
function checkObj (name,title,salary){
this.name= name;
this.title= title;
this.salary= salary;
}

checkObj.prototype.inc=function(){

var self=this;

for(var i in self){
    if(self.hasOwnProperty(i)){
        output(i);
    }
}

function output(item){
    if(typeof self[item]==='string'){
        self[item]=self[item].toUpperCase();
        console.log(self[item]);
    }
}
};
```

Is helpful for you ?